# How to read multiply delimited data in octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, time, octave

I have a file with many lines like this to read:

```
15:48:50.450    0.4 0.974   1.143   -0.008  2.5 60.5    18.9
```

The first element is a timestamp, and the rest are just real numbers.

There's also a header row at the top.

In Octave:

```
dlmread(file1,'\t :',1,0);
```

(read everything except the top line and treat tab, space and colon as separators)

Will pull out 15, 48, 50.450, 0.4, ...

from which it's easy to reconstruct the times.

Unfortunately, MATLAB won't accept multiple delimiters, and it is a bit of a hack anyway. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the file in using `dlmread` with the delimiter '\t' only, and then decompose the timestamp field using e.g. `datevec`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textscan` (*matlab*) to set up multiple delimiters and read the file

```
a = '15:48:50.450    0.4'
b = textscan(a,'%f%f%f%f','Delimiter',':\t')
```

that gives

```
a = 15:48:50.450    0.4

b = [15]    [48]    [50.4500]    [0.4000]
```